# Prove that $\bigcap_{\delta>0}A_\delta=\overline{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset of the metric space $M$ and for $\delta>0$ define

$$A_\delta=\{x\in M\mid(\exists a\in A)\, d(x,a)<\delta|\}$$

Prove that $\bigcap_{\delta>0} A_\delta=\overline{A}$

- I can only prove that $A_\delta$ is open...

Comment: Why do you write $\overline{\rm A}$ rather than $\overline A,$ i.e. you use \rm, where you had not used it when writing "Let $A$ be a subset"? $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall x \in \bigcap_{\delta > 0}A_{\delta}$, then $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $d(x,a) < \delta$, thus $x \in \bar A$.

$\forall x \in \bar A$: if $x \in A$ we are done. Else, $x$ is a limit point of $A$, and thus $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists a \in A$, s.t. $d(x,a) < \delta$, which means $x \in \bigcap_{\delta > 0}A_\delta$

So we are done,

Comment: You don't need to split $\overline A\subset\bigcap_{\delta>0}A_\delta$ into two cases.

Comment: @Aweygan Yes, you are right. I split just to make it clear, because $A \subset A_\delta$ by the definition of $A_\delta$ ($d(a,a) = 0 < \delta$), and this is not from the definition of limit point.